# Syntax Error in for

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, cycle

```
pts2d = np.array([[1.0486, -0.3645], [-1.6851, -0.4004], [-0.9437, -0.42], [1.0682, 0.0699], [0.6077, -0.0771], [1.2543, -0.6454], [-0.2709, 0.8635], [-0.4571, -0.3645], [-0.7902, 0.0307], [0.7318, 0.6382], [-1.058, 0.3312], [0.3464, 0.3377], [0.3137, 0.1189], [-0.431, 0.0242], [-0.4799, 0.292], [0.6109, 0.083], [-0.4081, 0.292], [-0.1109, -0.2992], [0.5129, -0.0575], [0.1406, -0.4527]])
pts3d = np.array([[1.5706, -0.149, 0.2598], [-1.5282, 0.9695, 0.3802], [-0.6821, 1.2856, 0.4078], [0.4124, -1.0201, -0.0915], [1.2095, 0.2812, -0.128], [0.8819, -0.8481, 0.5255], [-0.9442, -1.1583, -0.3759], [0.0415, 1.3445, 0.324], [-0.7975, 0.3017, -0.0826], [-0.4329, -1.4151, -0.2774], [-1.1475, -0.0772, -0.2667], [-0.5149, -1.1784, -0.1401], [0.1993, -0.2854, -0.2114], [-0.432, 0.2143, -0.1053], [-0.7481, -0.384, -0.2408], [0.8078, -0.1196, -0.2631], [-0.7605, -0.5792, -0.1936], [0.3237, 0.797, 0.217], [1.3089, 0.5786, -0.1887], [1.2323, 1.4421, 0.4506]])
u = pts2d[:,0]
v = pts2d[:,1]
X = pts3d[:,0]
Y = pts3d[:,1]
Z = pts3d[:,2]
A = np.zeros(40,12)
for i in range(1,2,40):
 for j in range ((i + 1) / 2): 
     A[i:i+1, :] = np.concatenate(X[j], Y[j], Z[j]  1, 0, 0, 0, 0 - u[j]*X[j]-u[j]*Y[j]-u[j]*Z[j]-u[j] 0, 0, 0, 0 X[j], Y[j], Z[j], 1 - v[j]*X[j]-v[j]*Y[j]-v[j]*Z[j]-v[j])
```

Error in `v[j]*X[j]`. Why I cant multiply them?

Comment: Consider more meaningful variable names and shorter line lengths. It will make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a few commas between some terms eg : `0 X[j]`
That's probably where your syntax error comes from.
You also need to put all those terms in a list for concatenate to work.

Here's the whole line for copy/pasting;

```
A[i:i+1, :] = np.concatenate([ X[j], Y[j], Z[j], 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 - u[j]*X[j]-u[j]*Y[j]-u[j]*Z[j]-u[j], 0, 0, 0, 0, X[j], Y[j], Z[j], 1 - v[j]*X[j]-v[j]*Y[j]-v[j]*Z[j]-v[j] ])
```

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that there seems to be other errors in your code, it probably doesn't do what you would expect it to do. And to write "good" numpy code you should always avoid building arrays with `for` loops.